# Merged two Git branches, pushed on server, now how to unmerge them

Tags: git, merge, push, production-environment

I have my code in master branch, then there is another branch named dev, dev is ahead of few commits than my master branch, before merging I even took a master branch backup 'master-backup'.

Then I merge dev into master, and push the merged master branch onto server (git push origin master).

So now my git log looks something like

commit 5 (already was in master)

commit 4 (came from dev branch)

commit 3 (came from dev-branch)

commit 2 (already was in master)

commit 1 (came from dev)

Rest of commits were already in both the branches

Above is the scenario, now the question I am stuck is I want to remove dev branch commits from master, I want my old master branch back, i.e whatever is in master-backup, I want the commits in master

How can I do so? since dev intermingled commits have already been merged into master and pushed, how can I remove dev branch and have my master back as it was?

Comment: You should be able to just reset your master branch to the same commit that master-backup points to, then do a forced push to the remote repository.  However, you'll lose any commits that have been made to master since you made the backup.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like, for an immediate fix, you can just replace `master` with `master-backup` on the server:

```
git push --force origin master-backup:master
```

For the slightly longer answer, you have two options.  The easiest is to use `git-reset`, but you should **only** do it if **no one else has seen this branch** or you will ruin her day.

The version of `master` one commit ago is called `master^`.  So first use `git log master^` to be *absolutely sure* it's the version you want to keep, and then with `master` checked out:

```
git reset --hard master^
```

And then to update on your server:

```
git push --force origin master
```

Your second option is to just use `git revert HEAD` to make a new commit undoing all the changes in your merge, and push that.  But that has [unexpected consequences](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt) if you try to merge again in the future.

Comment: Firstly, i have asked all others not to take a pull temporarily from the repo, secondly my server is still on previous version of master as the code hasnt been released yet.

But the point is I dont want to go back just one commit, as commits from dev branch are all over the place, as stated in question, there is a commit 3, commit 1 as well which I also want to remove, so just going back by one commit wont solve my problem, and I want to preserve my master commits as well, cant afford to lose them

Comment: excellent, you are on the ball.  you should be safe to overwrite `master` then.

Comment: But the point is I dont want to go back just one commit, as commits from dev branch are all over the place, as stated in question, there is a commit 3, commit 1 as well which I also want to remove, so just going back by one commit wont solve my problem, and I want to preserve my master commits as well, cant afford to lose them

Comment: but you do want to go back one commit—you did a merge, right?  your last commit is the merge between `master` and `dev`.  if you remove that, all the commits you brought in from `dev` go away too.  try `git log --oneline --graph --decorate` to see what i mean

Comment: Going back one commit will do so on your `master` branch, which should be the commit which `master` pointed to before the merge. In other words, all of the commits from `dev` will no longer appear in the `master` branch. To verify this for yourself, clone your repo and try it out.

Comment: or just make another copy of your `master` branch.  :)

Comment: oh yeah! right you are, that graph did increase my understanding of git. But I have will do a force push right? I have heard force push has negative consequences, is it a safe bet? heard it may lead to problems, not to forget more people are also working on this repo, will it affect their work

Comment: i have that aliased as `git lg` since it's so useful  :)  and yes, if you want to remove or change commits, you have to do a force-push.  it only causes problems if other people have already fetched the branch—in this case, if they try to push after you fixed `master`, they might push the bad merge again!  but you told everyone not to pull, so you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to push master-backup back in as master? `git checkout master-backup` then `git push -f origin master`.

Comment: I have heard force push has negative consequences, is it a safe bet? heard it may lead to problems, not to forget more people are also working on this repo, will it affect their work, they are still on last safe commit on master, havent taken the latest master as of yet

Comment: @grandmaster As long as no one else has pulled the new master, you should be fine. The problems occur when someone has pulled a committed branch and started work based on it. Then a forced commit will cause serious headaches for that person.

Comment: If everyone is still at the latest commit of master-backup, it should be fine.